# UWP App unknown exception

Tags: debugging, exception, win-universal-app

I am making a media app. In which I load playlists and then when I play from one playlist, it plays fine, but I have the same file in another playlist, It gives an exception, of system dubugger like this

[image]

I am using following code when gridview selection changes to play the file.

```
 private async void PlaylistGridView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (PlaylistGridView.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                CurrentlyPlayingVideo = (VideoFile)PlaylistGridView.SelectedItem;
                CurrentlyPlayingFile = CurrentlyPlayingVideo.File;
                var s = await CurrentlyPlayingFile.OpenReadAsync();
                var sq = me;
                me.SetSource(s, CurrentlyPlayingFile.ContentType);
            }
        }
        catch { }

    }
```

the message in e.Message is 'Object refrence is not set to instance of object',
I surely know it is null type error, but problem is i dnt know which object is null!!, I am even using try catch blocks, but still its giving that exception in the picture above, and not telling me the object which is null, until i dnt know which object is null, how can i fix the error?

**EDIT :**

I tried to run in release mode with visual studio and this is the error i get even before trying to play anything.

[image]

Comment: Did you try with a breakpoint on the try clause and checking each value manually?

Comment: yes I did that and all values seem perfectly fine

Comment: Then the problem is not in that block

Comment: yes i know problem seems to be somewhere else but it is unknown, before exception occurs, even the 2nd video plays fine, tht means the code block is working fine

Comment: Check the call stack trace, set debugging messages and place breakpoints everywhere. Not much can be done aside from that.

Comment: call stack shows that error is coming from App.xaml.cs and method Initialize component

Comment: @MuhammadTouseef the problem seems to be in your first two lines of code inside try-catch.See the debug results there. What every variable contains and whther the types are compatible.

Comment: @rahul jha I put breakpoint and have already checked that, these variables are fine

Answer (score 0):

```
Object reference is not set to instance of an object
```

I had seen this error when I build an uwp too. If I'm not mistaken, any of your `Control` (`Button` , `Textblock` , etc) is called by any of your method (including event) before they have been initialized to the `Page` Check the calling once again

Comment: building is not a problem app runs, fine it occurs when i try to play same video from different playlist again, the 2nd time video runs fine but dubugger throws an exception